# Can you use jemalloc arenas to implement 32-bit pointers on a 64-bit architecture?

Tags: c, posix, mmap, jemalloc

Is it possible to set up an arena with jemalloc that only allocates pages from a reserved 2^32 byte area of virtual memory

```
void* arena_start = 
       mmap(nullptr, 1ull<<32, 
            PROT_NONE, 
            MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 
            -1, 0);
```

so that any pointer allocated from the arena with `mallocx` using the `MALLOCX_ARENA` option for the arena can be represented as a 32-bit index from `arena_start`.

The motivation for this is pointer compression for more space-efficient data structures. (See the paper [Tranparent Pointer Compression for Linked DataStructures](https://llvm.org/pubs/2005-06-12-MSP-PointerComp.pdf) for background on similar use cases.)

The comments from [this thread](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/700#issuecomment-380569375) on arenas make me think this type of customization may be supported.

Comment: @M.M - good point. I made a correction.

Comment: Note: your *client* code probably has alignment requirements, so you could scale down index by sizeof (alignment); probably 8.